# Get input value from parent document

Tags: php, variables, curl

I'm using `CURL` to scrape a website like this:

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.bbc.com/news/";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$curl_scraped_page = preg_replace("#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)([\"'>]+)#",'$1http://www.bbc.com/news/$2$3', $curl_scraped_page);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
?>
```

As you can see the `URL` is set for BBC news. However, I would like the `URL` to be a variable instead. The variable would have to be the value of `parent.document`. In `JQuery` for example I would do this:

```
var value = $("input", parent.document.body).val();
```

How do I set something like that in `PHP`? I have Googled but I couldn't find anything about `parent.document` in PHP.

Comment: You can pass `value` through `GET` parameter to the script.

Comment: @fedosov Hi I know about that. The problem is that the php is in iframe and I need to get the value from its parent window (one level up)

Comment: @Youss so, can you update `iframe` content after altering an `input` value in parent window with `value` passed as `GET` parameter?

Comment: @fedosov Im not sure what you mean but I think yes, the iframe(with php code) is loaded on submit of the input.

Comment: @Youss sorry, english is not my native language. I mean, why you don't pass the `value` variable from `js` to `php` through `GET` parameter on `submit`?

Comment: Because I would like to keep the content as clean as possible(in iframe). If I do it with GET parameter I would have to echo on the same document with the ajax get code. This will screw up the php content.

Comment: What do you mean 'clean'? Also no `HTML` can corrupt your `PHP` code since the `PHP` can't be modified after the `HTML` is sent to the client.

Comment: If the page is echode on same page you will get this: <html><body><html of scraped page><body of scraped page></body></html> But if you echo in iframe you will get a proper document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PHP` is a server-side scripting language and therefore has no access to the current `HTML` page. It is processed before the `HTML` is sent to the client's browser, therefore `parent.document` doesn't even exist at the time the script is being processed.

If you would like to pass data from an `HTML` page to a `PHP` script, you can do so using an `HTML` `<form>` or through `JavaScript`/`JQuery` `AJAX` requests.

For example, the following code will pass the value of `input` to the `PHP` script:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function pass(){
    var value = $("input", parent.document.body).val(); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myscript.php",
        data: { mydata: value }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" />
<button onclick="pass();return false;">Pass Value</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And the revised script (myscript.php):

```
<?php
$url = isset($_POST['mydata']) ? $_POST['mydata'] : '';
$curl_scraped_page = '';

if(!empty($url)){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $curl_scraped_page = preg_replace("#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)([\"'>]+)#",'$1'.$url.'$2$3', $curl_scraped_page);
}

echo $curl_scraped_page;
?>
```

I would recommend using $(id) to retrieve the value of an `<input>` instead of `$("input",context)`.

E.g.

```
var value = $('#txt').val();
```

And in the `HTML`:

```
<input type="text" id="txt" />
```

For more info on `JQuery.ajax` see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Thank you. I did it before with ajax get but the problem is that the content will be somehowe "next" to the ajax code. Do you think its possible to echo the content in an iframe instead, so the content will be "clean"?

Comment: Just modify the `done` function of the `AJAX`. In the code I posted, it will display all the content in an `alert`. You can choose where you want to display the content. If you wanted to modify an `IFrame` you could use `$('#frame').contents().html(msg);` (I believe). To display the content in a `div` just do `$('#myDiv').html(msg);`

Comment: Thank you very much:-) Just in case someone is looking this is also possible   `var iframeBody  = $("iframe").contents ().find ("body");
        iframeBody.append (msg);`

Comment: I just tried your code for the iframe but nothing happend..My code is also not ideal..its different then echo because its appending the complete page(with head etc) to body..If you know anything better please let me know

Comment: Don't use `.find("body").append(msg)`, use `.html(msg)` as I said previously. Unless you want to append the data?

Comment: Oke thanks again:-) And also very VERY BIG thank you for preg_replace, that is something I could have never figured out myself.